# SVG cross-browser rendering

Tags: svg

I want to use SVG images instead of raster. Is there a good way to support IE 8 and below and maby some other out-of-date browsers? And to be sure that rendering is the same in all browsers?
Yes, this question has already been asked, but now is 2016 and probably new solutions appeared. Thanks.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-svg-fallbacks/ sums up every fallback scenario known to man until mid-2015.

Comment: _“but now is 2016”_ – which is why IE 8 support should not really be a concern any more. (Unless you’re talking about a restricted environment such as a corporate network for example – but that would rather change the scope of the question. Other than that – _progressive enhancement_ is the way to go.)

Comment: You might like to try RaphaelJS.  It supports IE <= 8 using VML.  Unfortunately the site seems to be down just now (as I write this) . http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: IE 6-8 is now (nov 2016) used by less than 0,5% (globally). http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Answer (score 0):

If IE 8 support concerns you - this very simple hack should work:

```
<img src="your.svg" onerror="this.src='your.png'">
```

Usage of anything below 8 is so low as to not be worth considering at this point.